Shap IndexError :index 16 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 16
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,MinMaxScaler,RobustScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error,mean_absolute_error,mean_absolute_percentage_error


from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout,BatchNormalization,LayerNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, Input,regularizers
import statistics

os.listdir('/content/')
file_path = '/content/pythondf.csv'
dfload = pd.read_csv(file_path)






dfload = dfload.drop(dfload.columns[0], axis=1)
# Define a function to add '00:00:00' if time component is missing
def add_missing_time_component(date_str):
    if len(date_str) == 10:  # Assuming 'YYYY-MM-DD' format
        return date_str + ' 00:00:00'
    return date_str

# Apply the function to the DateTime column
dfload['DateTime'] = dfload['DateTime'].apply(add_missing_time_component)

# Now convert the DateTime column to datetime format
dfload['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfload['DateTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')


# Convert the datetime column to datetime objects
dfload['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfload['DateTime'])

# Extract hour of the day, day of the week, and month of the year
dfload['hour'] = dfload['DateTime'].dt.hour
dfload['day_of_week'] = dfload['DateTime'].dt.dayofweek  # Monday=0, Sunday=6
dfload['month'] = dfload['DateTime'].dt.month

# Convert these variables to dummy variables
#df_hour_dummies = pd.get_dummies(dfload['hour'], prefix='hour').astype(int)
#df_day_dummies = pd.get_dummies(dfload['day_of_week'], prefix='day_of_week').astype(int)
#df_month_dummies = pd.get_dummies(dfload['month'], prefix='month').astype(int)



# Generate lagged features for temperature
for lag in [198,336,504]:
    dfload[f'load_lag_{lag}'] = dfload['Load_DA'].shift(lag)

dfload["Rolling_Avg_15"] = dfload["Load_DA"].rolling(window=15*24).mean().shift(7*24)
dfload["Rolling_Std_15"] = dfload["Load_DA"].rolling(window=15*24).std().shift(7*24)
dfload["Rolling_Sum_15"] = dfload["Load_DA"].rolling(window=15*24).sum().shift(7*24)
dfload["Rolling_Avg_30"] = dfload["Load_DA"].rolling(window=30*24).mean().shift(7*24)
dfload["Rolling_Sum_30"] = dfload["Load_DA"].rolling(window=30*24).sum().shift(7*24)
# Calculate the moving standard deviation over the last 30 days, excluding the first 7 days
dfload["Rolling_Std_30"] = dfload["Load_DA"].rolling(window=30*24).std().shift(7*24)

for lag in range(1, 4):
    dfload[f'temp_lag_{lag}'] = dfload['temp_actual'].shift(lag)

# Generate rolling mean features for temperature
for window in [6,24]:
    dfload[f'temp_mean_{window}'] = dfload['temp_actual'].rolling(window=window).mean()

# Generate min and max features for temperature over the last 24 hours
 ##temp_min_24 =  dfload['temp_actual'].rolling(window=24).min()

 #dfload['temp_max_24'] =  dfload['temp_actual'].rolling(window=24).max()

# Generate lag features for temperature at 24, 48, and 96 hours
for lag in [24, 48]:
     dfload[f'temp_lag_{lag}'] =  dfload['temp_actual'].shift(lag)

# Generate lag features for wind speed
#for lag in range(1, 8):
 #    dfload[f'wspd_lag_{lag}'] =  dfload['wspd_actual'].shift(lag)

#for lag in range(1, 8):
 #   dfload[f'dwpt_lag_{lag}'] = dfload['dwpt_actual'].shift(lag)

#for lag in range(1, 8):
  #dfload[f'pres_lag_{lag}'] = dfload['pres_actual'].shift(lag)

#for window in [2,4,8,12,24]:
 #   dfload[f'dew_mean_{window}'] = dfload['dwpt_actual'].rolling(window=window).mean()
# Generate min and max features for temperature over the last 24 hours
dfload['temp_min'] =  dfload['temp_actual'].rolling(window=24).min()
dfload['temp_max'] =  dfload['temp_actual'].rolling(window=24).max()


# Assuming df is your DataFrame with relevant columns

# Wind Chill calculation
#def calculate_wind_chill(temp, wind_speed):
 #   # Only calculate wind chill if temperature < 10°C and wind speed > 4.8 km/h
  #  wind_chill = np.where(
   #     (temp < 10) & (wind_speed > 4.8),
    #    13.12 + 0.6215 * temp - 11.37 * (wind_speed ** 0.16) + 0.3965 * temp * (wind_speed ** 0.16),
     #   temp
    #)
    #return wind_chill

# Humidity calculation
#def calculate_humidity(temp, dew_point):
 #   humidity = 100 * (np.exp((17.625 * dew_point) / (dew_point + 243.04)) /
  #                    np.exp((17.625 * temp) / (temp + 243.04)))
   # return humidity

# Apply the calculations to the DataFrame
#dfload['Wind_Chill'] = calculate_wind_chill(dfload['temp_actual'], dfload['wspd_actual'])
#dfload['Humidity'] = calculate_humidity(dfload['temp_actual'], dfload['dwpt_actual'])


#for lag in range(1, 6):
   # dfload[f'Wind_Chill_L{lag}'] = dfload['Wind_Chill'].shift(lag)
 #   dfload[f'Humidity_L{lag}'] = dfload['Humidity'].shift(lag)

#for window in [4,8,12,24]:
    #dfload[f'Wind_Chill_M{window}'] = dfload['Wind_Chill'].rolling(window=window).mean()
   # dfload[f'Humidity_M{window}'] = dfload['Humidity'].rolling(window=window).mean()

#Example: "Climate Change and Energy Demand in France" by Hallegatte et al., which discusses the impact of temperature on energy demand and uses 18°C as a reference for HDD.
T_base = 18

# Calculate HDD and CDD
dfload['HDD'] = dfload['temp_actual'].apply(lambda x: max(0, T_base - x))

dfload['CDD'] = dfload['temp_actual'].apply(lambda x: max(0, x - T_base))
#for lag in range(1, 8):
    #dfload[f'HDD_L{lag}'] = dfload['HDD'].shift(lag)
   # dfload[f'CDD_L{lag}'] = dfload['CDD'].shift(lag)
#for window in [4,6,8,12,24]:
 #   dfload[f'HDD_M{window}'] = dfload['HDD'].rolling(window=window).mean()
  #  dfload[f'CDD_M{window}'] = dfload['CDD'].rolling(window=window).mean()

#dfload['dwpt_min'] =  dfload['dwpt_actual'].rolling(window=24).min()
#dfload['dwpt_max'] =  dfload['dwpt_actual'].rolling(window=24).max()
#dfload['pres_min'] =  dfload['pres_actual'].rolling(window=24).min()
#dfload['pres_max'] =  dfload['pres_actual'].rolling(window=24).max()
#fload['wspd_min'] =  dfload['wspd_actual'].rolling(window=24).min()
#dfload['wspd_max'] =  dfload['wspd_actual'].rolling(window=24).max()
#dfload['HDD_min'] =  dfload['HDD'].rolling(window=24).min()
#dfload['HDD_max'] =  dfload['HDD'].rolling(window=24).max()
#dfload['CDD_min'] =  dfload['CDD'].rolling(window=24).min()
#dfload['CDD_max'] =  dfload['CDD'].rolling(window=24).max()
#dfload['Wind_Chill_min'] =  dfload['Wind_Chill'].rolling(window=24).min()
#dfload['Wind_Chill_max'] =  dfload['Wind_Chill'].rolling(window=24).max()
#dfload['Humidity_min'] =  dfload['Humidity'].rolling(window=24).min()
#dfload['Humidity_max'] =  dfload['Humidity'].rolling(window=24).max()

# Combine original DataFrame with dummy variables
#f_combined = pd.concat([dfload, df_hour_dummies, df_day_dummies, df_month_dummies], axis=1)
#f_combined = pd.concat([dfload, df_day_dummies, df_month_dummies], axis=1)
#dfload['hourdm'] =pd.get_dummies(dfload['hour'], prefix='hour').astype(int)
#f_combined = pd.concat([dfload, df_day_dummies, df_month_dummies], axis=1)
dfx = pd.concat([dfload.drop(columns=['dwpt_actual','wspd_actual','pres_actual'])], axis=1)
#dfx = pd.concat([f_combined.drop(columns=['month','day_of_week','wspd_actual'])], axis=1)

window = slice(9505, 44545)
train_val_set = dfx[window]

test_set = dfx[44545:]
#features = train_val_set[features]#.drop(columns=['DateTime',  'Load_DA',  'Load_Act'])
#target = train_val_set['Load_DA'].values




    # Subset the features based on the selection
X_selected = train_val_set[['temp_actual','hour','month','load_lag_198','load_lag_336','load_lag_504','Rolling_Avg_15','Rolling_Std_15',
 'Rolling_Sum_15','Rolling_Avg_30', 'temp_lag_2','temp_mean_24','temp_lag_48','temp_min','temp_max','CDD']]


target = train_val_set['Load_DA'].values

# Normalize the selected features
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_selected_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_selected)
target_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(target.reshape(-1, 1))

    # Reshape the target variable to have the shape (number of samples, 192)
y_reshaped = np.array([target_scaled[i:i+192] for i in range(0, len(target_scaled) - 192 + 1, 24)])

    # Adjust the input features accordingly
X_selected_scaled = np.array([X_selected_scaled[i:i+192, :] for i in range(0, len(X_selected_scaled) - 192 + 1, 24)])


    # Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_selected_scaled, y_reshaped, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)


inputs = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
ll = inputs



hidden_layer1 = layers.Dense(best_params['neurons_1'],
                                    activation=best_params['activation_1'])(ll)


#hidden_layer1 = LayerNormalization()(hidden_layer1)
hidden_layer2 = layers.Dense(best_params['neurons_2'],
                                    activation=best_params['activation_2'])(hidden_layer1)

    # Output layer
hidden_layer2 = LayerNormalization()(hidden_layer2)
outputs = layers.Dense(192,activation='linear')(hidden_layer2)

    # Define the model

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    # Compile the model
optimizer =  tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=best_params['learning_rate'])
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_absolute_error')
    # Train the mode
callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=50, restore_best_weights=True)]
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, callbacks=callbacks, batch_size=32, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    # Evaluate the model
loss = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
loss

Predictions :
`X_selected=test_set[['temp_actual','hour','month','load_lag_198','load_lag_336','load_lag_504','Rolling_Avg_15','Rolling_Std_15',
 'Rolling_Sum_15','Rolling_Avg_30', 'temp_lag_2','temp_mean_24','temp_lag_48','temp_min','temp_max','CDD']]


target = test_set['Load_DA'].values

    # Normalize the selected features
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_selected_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_selected)
target_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(target.reshape(-1, 1))

    # Reshape the target variable to have the shape (number of samples, 192)
y_t = np.array([target_scaled[i:i+192] for i in range(0, len(target_scaled) - 192 + 1, 24)])

    # Adjust the input features accordingly
X_t = np.array([X_selected_scaled[i:i+192, :] for i in range(0, len(X_selected_scaled) - 192 + 1, 24)])
# Make a prediction for the first sample in X_test
y_pred_single = model.predict(X_test[:1])  # This will output shape (1, 192, 192)

# Rescale the prediction back to the original scale
# Reshape to (1, 192, 1) by selecting the first feature if needed
y_pred_single_rescaled = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred_single.reshape(-1, 192)[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(1, 192, 1)

# Rescale the true value (y_test[:1]) back to the original scale
y_true_single_rescaled = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test[:1].reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(y_test[:1].shape)

# Check shapes after fixing
print(f"y_pred_single_rescaled shape: {y_pred_single_rescaled.shape}")
print(f"y_true_single_rescaled shape: {y_true_single_rescaled.shape}")

# Calculate the MAE for the single prediction
mae_single = mean_absolute_error(y_true_single_rescaled.flatten(), y_pred_single_rescaled.flatten())


And Shap
selected_features = {'temp_actual','hour','month','load_lag_198','load_lag_336','load_lag_504','Rolling_Avg_15','Rolling_Std_15',
 'Rolling_Sum_15','Rolling_Avg_30', 'temp_lag_2','temp_mean_24','temp_lag_48','temp_min','temp_max','CDD'}


# Initialize the explainer with the model and a sample of training data
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model.predict, X_train[:100])

# Calculate SHAP values for the test set predictions
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_t[0])  # Adjust the sample size if necessary

# Visualize the SHAP values for the first prediction
#shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_[0], feature_names=selected_features)

I wanted to find the Shap Values for the predictions but could not find a way to solve the error.
Here is the error. Btw, I tried to reshape or flatten the inputs but it didn't work.
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 9>()
7
8 # Calculate SHAP values for the test set predictions
----> 9 shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_t[0])  # Adjust the sample size if necessary
10
11 # Visualize the SHAP values for the first prediction
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/shap/utils/_legacy.py in (.0)
88     if isinstance(data, DenseData):
89         if instance.group_display_values is None:
---> 90             instance.group_display_values = [instance.x[0, group[0]] if len(group) == 1 else "" for group in data.groups]
91         assert len(instance.group_display_values) == len(data.groups)
92         instance.groups = data.groups
IndexError: index 16 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 16
Or any suggestion that would help me to get Shap values?
P.S: Shape of X_test = (364,192,16)
